# boost the speed of recusrive function

Tags: python, python-3.x

The function is too slow, or infinite, i didnt get the result. how to fix that?

```py
def x(a):
    return x(a - 1) + x(a - 2) + 42 if a > 1 else a
print(x(195))
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Use `functools.cache` to save the results of each call to `x()`.

```
from functools import cache

@cache
def x(a):
    return x(a - 1) + x(a - 2) + 42 if a > 1 else a

print(x(195))  # 1744559950484785950724677014047127864991062
```

Answer (score 4):

You can avoid recursion by using a simple for loop as follows:

```
def x(a: int) -> int:
    if a <= 1:
        return a

    p, q = 0, 1

    for _ in range(2, a + 1):
        p, q = q, p + q + 42

    return q
```

There you go.